# Remove quote on certain areas using regex in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove the single quote and double quotes from certain areas

```
[{"id":"'40011493'","quantity":1},{"id":"'40010663'","quantity":1},{"id":"'40010994'","quantity":1},{"id":"'40011003'","quantity":2}]
```

I want to be like this

```
[{id:'40011493',quantity:1},{id:'40010663',quantity:1},{id:'40010994',quantity:1},{id:'40011003',quantity:2}]
```

This is what I've got

```
found.replace(/\"([^(\")"]+)\":/g,"$1:");
```

But I can't get the remaining double quote

```
 [{id:"'40011493'",quantity:1},{id:"'40010663'",quantity:1},{id:"'40010994'",quantity:1},{id:"'40011003'",quantity:2}]
```

Comment: This is very weird. Your original format is proper JSON and should be preferable in all situations. You can remove the `'`s from the *inner values*, but turning it into invalid JSON doesn't make sense

Comment: Are you looking for a way to turn id into a number?

Comment: I'm trying to put that format in FB pixel using GTM, @Gbr22 I want to maintain the single qoute in id. Thanks!

Comment: and isn't this good? `"40011493"`

Comment: what can I add in my script to achieve that? though it's single qoute in fb documentation.

Comment: there's no difference between double, and single quoted strings

Comment: I see. In my case I got both.

Comment: Just to re-iterate what others have said, in *javascript* there is no difference between single and double quotes. It certainly makes sense to remove the inner single-quotes. However, in JSON it *does* matter. JSON doesn't support single quotes, and the keys must be quoted. FB docs are probably showing you javascript objects that you pass to their API (or JSON.stringify before passing to their API, however it works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove starting and ending single quotes, you can use this regex:

```
/^'|'$/g
```

To remove all single quotes you can use this:

```
/'/g
```

Example:

```js
let data = [{"id":"'40011493'","quantity":1},{"id":"'40010663'","quantity":1},{"id":"'40010994'","quantity":1},{"id":"'40011003'","quantity":2}]

function removeQuote(s){
    let regex = /^'|'$/g;
    return s.replace(regex,'');
}

data.forEach(e=>{
  e.id = removeQuote(e.id);
})
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks @Gbr22 How can I remove the qoute from keys? (id/quantity)

Comment: The quote in the keys doesn't make a difference in javascript

Comment: But in json if you omit the quotes for keys, then it is invalid

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I think I'll go for removing the qoutes .to satisfy the fb docs.

Answer (score 0):

To neglect the double-quote and to match with other remaining test string you can try this,

Regular Expression: `/[^"]+/g` or `/[[{:\w\\d',\d}]+]*/g`

https://regex101.com/r/8GvSZ0/3

https://regex101.com/r/8GvSZ0/2

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with a javascript object you'd only want to get rid of the extra quotes in the value of the id property. Your quantity is a number so no action needed on it.

As for the quotes on the keys it's the same whether you omit them or explicitly define them.

I suggest you loop through the array and apply regex only on the id to remove redundant quotes.

```js
const input = [{
  "id": "'40011493'",
  "quantity": 1
}, {
  "id": "'40010663'",
  "quantity": 1
}, {
  "id": "'40010994'",
  "quantity": 1
}, {
  "id": "'40011003'",
  "quantity": 2
}];


const output = input.map(obj => ({
  ...obj,
  id: obj.id.replace(/["']/g, '')
}));

console.log('output', output);
```